# When should I use socket and when should I use HTTP in Android?

Tags: android, sockets, http, networking

**I have known the difference between socket and http.
**Recently,i have to develop an app including upload pictures and videos and chat to others.
I should use http or socket? 
maybe I should use both of them?**
**can u explain when we use http and when we should use socket**.(no just difference)**

Comment: `I have known the difference between socket and http`. Very good. So now you know that http runs between sockets? HTTP uses sockets. Your question is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Well with a socket you will communicate with an IP and a port like 127.0.0.1 4242.
It's efficient for exemple to communicate between a game and is server, or between a ftp client and is server.
The connexion is maintened between the server and the client

With HTTP you don't have permanent connexion so you will be able to POST and GET data when you want.
In your case you will POST data picture and video to a dedicated url of your backend. without have to be connected permanently to it.

For the chat it's different if you want real time chat you have to maintain a connexion between the user and the chat server to be able to send and receive message quickly. You should take a look at XMPP protocole (I use it with [aSmack](https://github.com/flowdalic/asmack) library for android with [eJaberred](https://www.ejabberd.im) server)

Comment: I have also use xmpp protocal(i use aSmack and openfire).As you said.should i set 2 server , one for share picture and video, one for instant chatting.

Comment: Personnaly i have one server for my application database and one other for the chat. And it work verry well. I don't know if it's the best way to do but it seem ok to me